# Look through text files for a certain text and insert to SQL

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm trying to optimize my Powershell Script a little.
I have a lot of log (text) files, that i need to search through the content of, for a specific text entry.
If the entry is found, I need the script to trigger with an inset to an sql databse.

This is what I have for now:

```
$tidnu = (Get-Date -f dd.MM.yyyy)
$Text = "ERROR MESSAGE STACK"
$PathArray = @()
$NodeName = "SomeName"
$Logfil = "SomeLogFile"

Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*ORA11*.log" |
Where-Object { $_.Attributes -ne "Directory"} |
  ForEach-Object {
     If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text)
     {
        $PathArray += $_.FullName
        $cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO ErrorTabel (Datotid, Nodename, Logfil, ErrorFound) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')" -f $tidnu, $NodeName, $Logfil, "Yes"
        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     }
     else
     {                      
        $cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO ErrorTabel (Datotid, Nodename, ErrorFound) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}')" -f $tidnu, $NodeName, "No"
        $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
     }
  }
```

This is working okay, but when i need to move to another log file name, i have simply made the same code again with different inputs. 
What i would like to do, is to use an Array, and a foreach loop, so i could specify all the log files in one array, like:

```
$LogArray = @(Log1.log, log2.log, log3.log)
```

And specify all the Nodenames like:

```
$NodeArray = @(Node1, Node2, Node3)
```

And then make a foreach loop that will go through the logfiles one by one and insert into the databse, with it's matching nodename every time the loop runs through.

Can someone help me to make this happen? I have the idea on how it should be done, but I can't figure out how to write the code. All help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

Ok, this is what i have now then, but i'm not sure that it's correct put together. Its giving me some strange results.

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=PCDK03918;Initial Catalog=Rman;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$conn.open()
$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.connection = $conn

$tidnu = (Get-Date -f dd.MM.yyyy)
$Path = "C:\RMAN"
$Text = "ERROR MESSAGE STACK"


$nodes = @{
  'NodeName1' = 'Node1log1.log', 'Node1log2.log', 'Node1log3.log'
  'NodeName2' = 'Node2log1.log', 'Node2log2.log'
}

foreach ($NodeName in $nodes.Keys) {
foreach ($Logfil in $nodes[$NodeName]) {


Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.log" |

ForEach-Object {
 If (Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $Text)
 {       
    $cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO Error (Datotid, Nodename, Logfil, Error) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')" -f $tidnu, $NodeName, $Logfil, "Yes"
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 }
 else
 {                      
    $cmd.commandtext = "INSERT INTO Error (Datotid, Nodename, Logfil, Error) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')" -f $tidnu, $NodeName, $Logfil, "No"
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   }
  }  
 }
}
$conn.close()
```

I have created the log files mentioned in $nodes, in the folder, and put the "ERROR MESSAGE STACK" into Node1log1.log and Node1log2.log The rest of the log files are with no "ERROR MESSAGE STACK" inside.

But the result in the database is strange. It says Error = Yes to log files with no "ERROR MESSAGE STACK" inside, and it says Error = No to the same log files some rows down. Plus its inserting double rows and all in all its not doing as intended.

could it be because my

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.log" |
```

is wrong by using *.log ?

Or am I simply going completely wrong about this?

EDIT Once more:

Not sure what I was thinking yesterday, but I believe i have solved it now.

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter "*.log" |
```

Will of course not work.

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter $logfil |
```

Gives much more sense, and now my databse output is looking much more correct.

@Ansgar Wiechers - Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I learned alot from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a hashtable for this:

```psh
$logs = @{
  'Log1.log' = 'Node1'
  'Log2.log' = 'Node2'
  'Log3.log' = 'Node3'
}
```

That way you can iterate over the logs like this:

```psh
foreach ($Logfil in $logs.Keys) {
  $NodeName = $logs[$Logfil]
  ...
}
```

If you have more than one log file per node name, it would be more efficient to reverse the mapping and store the log file names in an array:

```psh
$nodes = @{
  'Node1' = 'Log1.log', 'Log2.log', 'Log3.log'
  'Node2' = 'Log4.log', 'Log5.log'
}
```

Then you can process the logfiles with a nested loop like this:

```psh
foreach ($NodeName in $nodes.Keys) {
  foreach ($Logfil in $nodes[$NodeName]) {
    ...
  }
}
```

You should be able to fit your pipeline into either loop without further modifications.

**Edit:** As an optimization you could do something like this to avoid needlessly fetchin logs with each iteration of the outer loop:

```psh
$logs = Get-ChildItem $Path -Filter '*.log'

foreach ($NodeName in $nodes.Keys) {
  $logs | ? { $nodes[$NodeName] -contains $_.Name } | % {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. Not sure i follow completely tho.  Lets say i have two different nodenames, like: NodeName1 and NodeName2.  NodeName1 has 2 logfiles connected to it. NodeName2 has 3 logfiles connected to it. All log files have different names.  How can I look through those 5 logfiles, with a combination of what i have now, and what you are suggesting?  Im faily new to coding, so please if you can, try to be more specific. I would realy appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. Please see updated first post.

Comment: @G.T Sorry, I didn't realize that the logs were meant to be fetched by `Get-ChildItem`,  but it looks like you already found a solution. I'd recommend a slightly different approach for reading/filtering the logs, though, to avoid needless operations in the loop. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, again. I have tried both ways out. And they both work very good. I'm able to add all the different node names and their corresponding log files, into the array. And it's giving a very good result in the database. Also it's now very easy to add new nodes and logs to the script. Thank you again for all your help. I learned a lot from this.